# ExoPlayer - how to play local mp3 file

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm trying to use ExoPlayer instead of MediaPlayer because it's a common bug that MediaPlayer returns wrong getCurrentPosition() and I need a substitute.

But I can't find an info anywhere how to open a local file through the file path to the file same as MediaPlayer's `.setDataSource(String filepath)`

Google doesn't have any example and the official documentation site strangely crash my FireFox browser on both computers

Comment: Which bug is that? Do you have a reference?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=android+media+player+getcurrentposition+bug

Answer (score 10):

The ExoPlayer demo app in github can be modified to play local files.
To do that, edit https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java file to add a new video set.

```
public static final Sample[] LOCAL_VIDEOS = new Sample[] {
   new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 1",
     "/mnt/sdcard/video1.mp4", DemoUtil.TYPE_OTHER),
  new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 2",
    "/mnt/sdcard/video2.mp4", DemoUtil.TYPE_OTHER),
};
```

To do that, edit https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java file to add a new sample set.

```
sampleAdapter.add(new Header("Local Videos"));
sampleAdapter.addAll((Object[]) Samples.LOCAL_VIDEOS);
```

Comment: Good reply, thank you! Anyway i think the use of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is a more anroid-like way.

Comment: @Srikanth can u pls share link again

Answer (score 5):

A minor modification with Srikanth Peddibhotla's code works

The Uri string for the file should be "file:///mnt/sdcard/YourFilename.mp4" instead of "/mnt/sdcard/YourFilename.mp4" in [Samples.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java)

```
public static final Sample[] LOCAL_VIDEOS = new Sample[] {
new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 1",
 "file:///mnt/sdcard/video1.mp4", DemoUtil.TYPE_MP4),
new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 2",
"file:///mnt/sdcard/video2.mp4", DemoUtil.TYPE_MP4),
};
```

Also, add the following lines to [SampleChooserActivity.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/SampleChooserActivity.java)

```
 sampleAdapter.add(new Header("Local Videos"));
 sampleAdapter.addAll((Object[]) Samples.LOCAL_VIDEOS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ExoPlayer 2.1, and starting with the `demo` project, you can play mp3 files from the `assets` folder without modifying any Java code, just by adding the mp3 files in the `assets` folder and creating or modifying a `json` file. Starting with the ExoPlayer `demo` project:

1. Put the mp3 files in the `demo/assets` folder (with `media.exolist.json`).
2. Either modify `media.exolist.json` or create a new file such as `my.exolist.json` containing one or more entries formatted like this:

`{
    "name": "Children's Songs",
    "samples": [
      {
        "name": "Mary Had a Little Lamb",
        "uri": "asset:///mary1.mp3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Itsy Bitsy Spider",
        "uri": "asset:///spider1.mp3"
      }
    ]
  },`

(The final comma assumes there will be another category following, such as `Blues Songs`, `Jazz Songs` etc. with more mp3 entries. The final category has no comma after it.)

The figure below shows the chooser activity screen after you click on `Children's Songs`:

[image: ExoPlayer Chooser Activity]

Click `Mary Had a Little Lamb` or `Itsy Bitsy Spider` and that mp3 plays.

Answer (score 0):

Google changed some variable name and class definition these days! Below differ works for me.

```
--- a/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/SampleChooserActivity.java
+++ b/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/SampleChooserActivity.java
@@ -30,6 +28,8 @@ import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
 import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.List;
@@ -44,7 +44,12 @@ public class SampleChooserActivity extends Activity {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.sample_chooser_activity);
     final List<SampleGroup> sampleGroups = new ArrayList<>();
-    SampleGroup group = new SampleGroup("YouTube DASH");
+
+    SampleGroup group = new SampleGroup("test videos");
+    group.addAll(Samples.LOCAL_VIDEOS);
+    sampleGroups.add(group);
+
+    group = new SampleGroup("YouTube DASH");
     group.addAll(Samples.YOUTUBE_DASH_MP4);
     group.addAll(Samples.YOUTUBE_DASH_WEBM);
     sampleGroups.add(group);
diff --git a/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java b/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java
index 9f58528..9e86f99 100644
--- a/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java
+++ b/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/Samples.java
@@ -248,6 +248,13 @@ import java.util.Locale;
         "http://vod.leasewebcdn.com/bbb.flv?ri=1024&rs=150&start=0", Util.TYPE_OTHER),
   };

+  public static final Sample[] LOCAL_VIDEOS = new Sample[] {
+          new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 1",
+                  "file:///mnt/sdcard/test1.mp4", Util.TYPE_OTHER),
+          new Sample("Some User friendly name of video 2",
+                  "file:///mnt/sdcard/test2.mp4", Util.TYPE_OTHER),
+  };
+
   private Samples() {}

 }
```