# #Reading audio formats and produce sound

Tags: android

I'm developing an android media player, and I need to work with audio formats like WAV and MP3. And I need to produce the sound after reading the files as bytes. Anybody knows how to do that or can help!
Note : It's necessary to not work with MediaPlayer class or another ready class, I need to read the files as bytes and produce sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use MediaPlayer?

Maybe try exoplayer.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

example code from [ExoPlayer - play local mp4 file in SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675105/exoplayer-play-local-mp4-file-in-sd-card)

```
private void prepareExoPlayerFromFileUri(Uri uri){
    exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector(null), new DefaultLoadControl());
    exoPlayer.addListener(eventListener);

    DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(uri);
    final FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource();
    try {
        fileDataSource.open(dataSpec);
    } catch (FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
        @Override
        public DataSource createDataSource() {
            return fileDataSource;
        }
    };
    MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(fileDataSource.getUri(),
            factory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);

    exoPlayer.prepare(audioSource);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, this program is related to my study so I need to build my own media player that support some formats as wav, mp3 and avi .So I cant use something like media player class or another ready classes. I have to read each format as bytes and produce the sound.